# Applications emitting desktop notifications freeze for some time

Tags: unity, notification

A few days ago, for a reason I won't get into here, I ran `sudo apt install ubiquity` on my Ubuntu 18.04, running Unity 7. The installation failed and I wanted to undo it. A few stupid commands later, I think I succeeded.

Unfortunately, the next time I booted, I got a strange problem: every program that tries to emit a desktop notification would freeze for 30 to 60 seconds. This includes:

- `notify-send`
- Messenger
- increasing/decreasing volume via volume buttons

Very annoying!

What can I do to solve this or investigate this?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I somehow broke the autostart of the notification implementation. In Unity's case that's `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/notify-osd`. That thing should be running. If it's not, the applications freeze.

So the solution is to add that executable to the startup applications.

There is some useful additional information here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_notifications

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is quite an old thread. But you, My Good Sir, just helped me fix the same issue after I had tried KDE Plasma Desktop(the `kde-plasma-desktop` package) on Ubuntu MATE 20.04. Somehow during the process, it had removed the `notify-osd` package. After seeing your answer, I ran:

```
sudo apt install notify-osd
```

After it got installed, I restarted the system…and voilà! It's fixed now! Thank you so so much!